# 404 error message for a specific word in subdomain

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url

I am displaying different websites depending on the venue name. Etc. venue called "badbooking" then the url will be badbooking.school.com, but if the venue subdomain called "space", instead of displaying the site and the url, it gives 404 error message. Only happening with this subdomain name.

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: If I read your question right are you saying that you're working on a Rails 3 web application and that you get 404 messages with subdomain of something like: 'spacealiens.school.com' ?

Comment: can you add more details what you have already tried and add screens shots? Question is very unclear.

Comment: Do you have wildcard subdomains configured in your DNS and on your server? How do you handle the `404` error in your app internally (please show some code)?

Comment: Schwad, yes, I got the error message, instead loading the website and the subdomain name is "space".

Comment: You can load space.school.com in a browser, right?